# SharpDX - Creating constant buffer crashes

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, directx, sharpdx

I am using SharpDX to create a basic DirectX program in C#. I am trying to pass some data down to the shaders using a constant buffer, however when I create the buffer DirectX crashes with an incorrect parameter. Enabling the debug layer is not giving me anymore information. My code looks like this:

```
consts = new ConstantBufferData() { fTime = 0.0f };
constantBuffer = D3D11.Buffer.Create<ConstantBufferData>(device, D3D11.BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, ref consts);
```

where ConstantBufferData is a struct defined like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct ConstantBufferData
{
    public float fTime;
};
```

Oddly, the entire program compiles and functions normally when I create the buffer as a vertex buffer, but use it as a constant buffer with `context.PixelShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, constantBuffer);`.

Comment: You're creating your buffer on the stack, I don't know SharpDX but I'd guess this is not intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used SharpDX but this seems like a badly constrained type parameter.
Checking the code at [SharpDX's github](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct3D11/Buffer.cs) I see it's using interop pointer to pass the pointer.

So I guess this could either a visibility issue, since `ConstantBufferData` is not defined as public.

Or a formal param issue, since as far as I can see in [CreateBuffer's doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476501(v=vs.85).aspx) the data parameter must comply with `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA` structure

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it has not changed anything. I did change ConstantBufferData to be public, but it did not help. Looking around online, none of the constant buffer examples have structs that follow `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA`. An example of this would be here: http://timjones.tw/blog/archive/2011/03/08/marshalling-c-structures-into-directd-cbuffers-using

Comment: Reading from the link you posted, I see there're problems with the struct format if it's not explicit. Did you try specifying the layout as Explicit, size and offset as is in the example?

Comment: Hah! That fixed it! I had tried setting the struct to be explicit and setting the field offsets, but I felt like setting the size would not matter for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Constant buffers size must be a multiple of 16, which is not the case of your struct (which is just 4), so creation will fail.

On the other side, Vertex buffer do not have this restriction, so resource would create successfully in that case.

If you get the debug device on, you should have this error message:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer: The Dimensions are invalid. For ConstantBuffers, marked with the D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER BindFlag, the ByteWidth (value = 4) must be a multiple of 16. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #66: CREATEBUFFER_INVALIDDIMENSIONS]

Two ways to fix this.

1/Add padding to your struct to fit a multiple of 16, eg:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct ConstantBufferData
{
    public float fTime;
    public int dum1,dum2,dum3;
};
```

Or enforce the size rule on buffer creation (make sure by size in description is a multiple of 16, in case your structur size is "size" then you have the following:

```
int paddedSize = ((size + 15) / 16) * 16;
```